# Is there anyway I can connect to Cloud SQL (SQL Server) with disabled public IP from BigQuery or Data Studio?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql, looker-studio

I have my database in Cloud SQL (SQL Server). The public IP is disabled.

I wanted to run some select queries on this database based on which I want to create a dashboard on Data Studio.

I tried following two approaches:

- **Cloud SQL federated queries:** Using BigQuery we can connect to Cloud
  SQL, but this is limited to MySQL and PostgreSQL.
  [Link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cloud-sql-federated-queries#:%7E:text=BigQuery%20Cloud%20SQL%20federation%20enables,with%20the%20SQL%20function%20EXTERNAL_QUERY.)
- **Using MS SQL Server Google Connector:** But I am not able to connect to
  my database since it is not public.

Is there anyway I can connect to Cloud SQL (SQL Server) with disabled public IP from BigQuery or Data Studio?

Comment: somehow in your case of course it also depends on the amount of your data, but assuming we're not talking about big data i would probably write a script, maybe using Cloud Run, to query the source database of the sql server and write the data to BigQuery which will make it better for analysis, you might consider this

Comment: @luisvenezian So, you are suggesting that replicating data to BigQuery is the only alternative in this scenario...right?

Comment: indeed, i just tried to be more explicative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can only perform BigQuery federated queries if you use:

- PostgreSQL or MySQL
- Have a public IP

You have none of 2.

For datastudio, it's an external tool, not attached to your project/VPC, and so, you can't access your database without a public IP.

Answer (score 1):

As Suggested by Guillaume, you cannot perform federated queries unless you're querying a PostgreSQL/MySQL instance or have a public IP.

However, in your scenario you can try replicating your data from SQL Server to BigQuery using Cloud Data Fusion as per this [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/tutorials/replicating-data/sqlserver-to-bigquery) and then perform queries in BigQuery.